# Android Studio 3.4 - Linux Mint MATE 18.3 can't type in editor

Tags: android-studio

I've installed Android Studio 3.4 on Linux Mint MATE 18.3.  I am trying to learn flutter/dart.  Everytime i type in the editor, it acts as if i am pressing the backspace key.  The letter would appear for a second and it's gone..

Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: Does it happen only in that program?

Comment: Yes  i also use intellij community edition and it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

i've uninstalled 3.4 and installed 3.3.  Then upgraded to 3.4 and this fixed the problem.